# How to prevent an application from showing up in the Unity panel?

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel

I need to remove an application completely from the Unity panel, [this post](http://goo.gl/1Hmj5) is a good start, it shows how to remove the menu but it does not remove the name from the panel. How can I do that?

Here is a picture of the text I want removed as requested.

[image: Name in the panel to be removed]

Comment: The question is unclear. Please explain it a bit better or/and provide pictures, these will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here you go a little screenshot ...

Comment: Eeeh, does it really matter?

Comment: Yes it does especially for apps like screenlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can create a ".desktop"-file with an empty name string or just a space " " for an application and the text won't be visible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove this text without editing the source for Unity and building it again. In other words, it is not possible to remove it so easily. You could however file a bug against unity (as a wishlist item) to have this text be made optional.